# remove b' character in csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I retrieved tweets from my twitter API and then tried to save the result as csv file.
Here's the code for saving it as csv file :

```
csvFile = open('test55.csv', 'w', newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
csvWriter.writerow(['time', 'username', 'tweet'])
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#covid19 -filter:retweets",count=500,
                           lang="in", tweet_mode='extended',
                           since="2021-02-27").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.full_text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'),tweet.full_text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8')])
```

The result in csv file :
b'usersA'
b'Here's a dummy text about covid-19 since I can't share the tweet result due to the Twitter API policy'

I tried to do text preprocessing on it using jupyter notebook. In order to remove b' prefix character I tried to decode it, but python categorized it as str type. So, it didn't do anything with the b' prefix.
Instead, I tried to remove the b' prefix character using regex. Here's the code :

```
def remove_tweet_special(text):
    text = text.replace("b/'","")
data_tweet['tweet'] = data_tweet['tweet'].apply(remove_tweet_special)
```

It didn't change anything. But, here's the result example :
bHere's a dummy text about covid-19 since I can't share the tweet result due to the Twitter API policy

Can anyone help me to remove the b' prefix using python 3?

Comment: Well why do you encode it if that's not what you want?

Comment: I couldn't save it to csv file without encoding it. It gives me codec error at some point, still try to learn more about it.

Comment: The `b''` prefix is the *repr* of a bytes object (byte string). Just don't write it encoded (which also converts a str to a bytes object). The csvFile is opened in text mode, and therefore expects `str` objects. Trying to remove it after it's written is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I tried without .encode('utf-8), it worked, but this happened :
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 37-40: character maps to <undefined>
It retrieved less tweets as well

Answer (score 0):

Your `.encode()` is what's giving you the `b'` "prefix":

```
In [1]: my_string = "This is my string."
   ...: my_string
Out[1]: 'This is my string.'

In [2]: my_string.encode()
Out[2]: b'This is my string.'
```

Just don't encode if you want to get rid of the `b'`.

Comment: I just tried without encode and this happened :
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 37-40: character maps to <undefined>
Also, I only retrieved 5 tweets only, when I use .encode('utf-8) I retrieved between 15-50 tweets. I think without .encode(utf-8) character that contains symbols and emoji got filtered out